# Android - how to use Html.ImageGetter in order to show number of images in edittext or text view

Tags: android, html, android-edittext

What i'm trying to do is, when a button pressed then an image will apper at the edittext field.

The thing is that i want to add the image few times - meaning on each click an image will add to the String.

The problem is that with the next code I'm only seeing the last pressed image and the previous images are turning into a small box with the letter 'obj'

Here is my Activity can anybody see what the problem is ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ImageGetter, OnClickListener {
EditText et;
ImageButton ib1;
ImageButton ib2;
ImageButton ib3;
Spanned spanned;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("main", "0001");

    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ib1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    ib3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    ib1.setOnClickListener(this);
    ib2.setOnClickListener(this);
    ib3.setOnClickListener(this);




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public Drawable getDrawable(String arg0) {


    int id = 0;

    if(arg0.equals("zero.png")){
        id = R.drawable.emoji_0030;
    }

    if(arg0.equals("slash.png")){
        id = R.drawable.emoji_0023;
    }
    LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
    Drawable empty = getResources().getDrawable(id);
    d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());

    return d;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

    case  R.id.imageButton2:

        toDisplay("zero.png");

        break;

    case   R.id.imageButton1:       
        toDisplay("slash.png");

        break;
    }

}


public void toDisplay(String input){

    String first = et.getText().toString();


    String second = "<img src ='"+input+"'>";
    String last = first +second;


     spanned = Html.fromHtml(last, this, null);

     et.setText(spanned);
     et.setTextSize(16);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that problem is in `et.getText().toString()`. It returns some text equivalent from   to HTML but not HTML source code itself. Try to change your `toDisplay(String input)`:

**EDIT**

```
public void toDisplay(String input){

    String first = Html.toHtml(et.getText());


    String second = "<img src ='"+input+"'>";
    String last = first +second;


     spanned = Html.fromHtml(last, this, null);

     et.setText(spanned);
     et.setTextSize(16);

}
```

But for me it adds new image on the new line. The reason why it happens is `Html.toHtml()` wraps text by `<p></p>` tags. I think you have to play with `String last = first +second;` to replace simple concatenation by insertion inside `<p></p>`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's not a good idea - because if i write something in the edittext and then adding an image, the text is deleted.

Comment: Shame it adds <p></p> to each row - it sure looks bad, not in one line as i hope it will be

Comment: The simplest way to fix it replace `String last = first +second;` to `String last = first.isEmpty()?second:first.replace("</p>", second + "</p>");`. But I believe you can find better solution based on your particular expectations.